# How to make change OBIEE RPD in online mode

Tags: obiee

When trying to open OBIEE RPD in online mode, I'm getting error window, RPD will open in Read-only mode. This means I can not make any changes. There are few option, which is enable when we open RPD in online mode. So, I need RPD open in online mode.

[image]

I tried all solution mentioned below links, but I'm still having same issue :

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2416619?tstart=0

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2290410?tstart=0

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2457755?tstart=0

http://siebel.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/siebel-analytics-l/unable-to-open-rpd-in-online-mode-1264337

None of the above links was helpful in my case. Could anyone suggest any other solution ?

PS : I'm using OBIEE 11g.

Comment: What does the error window say?

Comment: @MarkP. I have attached screenshot.

Comment: This may sound like an obvious question, but, is your BI server fully running?

Comment: @MarkP. Yes, it is running, otherwise I could have got BI server related error. right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

- Go to Enterprise Manager.
- Select the performance tab.
- Uncheck the “Disallow RPD Updates” checkbox.
- Apply the change and Restart the server.

Now try to edit in Online mode.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says that if you attempt to open a repository that is loaded into Oracle BI Server, the repository opens in read-only mode. Only one Administration tool session at a time can edit a repository in offline mode. If you want to edit the repository while it is loaded, you must open it in online mode.